# How to save form wizard with OneToOne Field

Tags: django, forms, formwizard

Django 1.6
I have 2 models:

1. User standard model
2. Profile

code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   class Meta:
       db_table = 'profile'
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=32)
   bdate = models.DateField()
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I register user with form wizard. At first user write username and password. Next he write profile fields. How can I save this information into models.
My view:

```
class UsrCreateProfile(SessionWizardView):
  template_name = 'user_registration.html'
  def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
      form_list[0].save()
      get_user_name = form_list[0]
      get_user_profile = form_list[1]
      get_user_name = get_user_name['username']
      user_get = User.objects.get(username=get_user_name)
      form_list[1].save(pk=user_get)
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

forms.py:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password1']
class UserRegistrationForm1(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'bdate', 'phone']
```

Template:

```
{% block reg_usr %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.error }}
{% endfor %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ wizard.management_form }}
        {% if wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ wizard.form.management_form %}
            {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                {{ form }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            {{ wizard.form }}
        {% endif %}
        </table>
        {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
        <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">First step</button>
        <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">Prev step</button>
        {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: What did you try ? Do you have any code so far ?

Comment: I want register user. Have form wizard with two pages. First page - username and password(registration) and the second page - user information(first name, lats name, email and phone). I want to save this into base. But i can't save user information because i haven't go user_id. How can I get user id and save profile information from second page. Thanks.

Comment: Try saving `form_list[1]` to get/create user and then `form_list[0]`.

Comment: I must have user_id to save form_list[1] into base.

Comment: @Vitek the return value of `form_list[0].save()` should be the user object itself. Just use its id to assign into profile.

Comment: method save() returns nothing.

Comment: @Vitek is the `form_list[0]` a model form or base form? Can you show the definitions of both forms?

Comment: @Vitek did you resolve this problem? Just having the same now.